# How to define a json output using swagger

Tags: swagger

I have a json payload  and I need some help on how to represent it in swagger-YAML

keywords can be an empty array [] or and array like ['a','b','c']

Here is my object

```
{
    "keywords": [],
    "distance": "25",
    "jobType": "all",
    "sectorId": "0",
    "location": {
        "lat": "33.7489954",
        "lng": "-84.3879824",
        "name": "Atlanta, GA"
    }
}
```

---

This is what I have so far but I am getting the error

```
SyntaxError: Data does not match any schemas from "oneOf" 
Data path: "/paths/~1users~1{userId}~1jobdeckSearch/get/responses/200" 
Schema path: "/properties/paths/patternProperties/^~1/properties/get/properties/responses/patternProperties/^([0-9]{3})$|^(default)$/oneOf"


responses:
        200:
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              distance:
                type: string
              keywords:
                type: array
                items: 
                  type: string
              jobType:
                type: string
              sectorId:
                type: string
              location:
                 properties:
                   lat:
                     type: string
                   lng:
                    type: string
                  name:
                    type: string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response codes require a `description`:

```
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            ...
```

Also, remove the extra space character before `lat` and `lng` - they need to be indented at the same level as `name`.

Other than that, you definition is fine.